# Visual Studio 2017 project is targeting .NET Framework version 4.7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Just installed vs 2017 and trying to load a project. I am running windows 10 (which has .NET 4.7) but I keep getting this error. I also can't install using the vs installer as the component isn't there. Anyone had this issue yet?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the targeting pack directly from the command line

```
vs_installer.exe modify --installPath "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional" --Add Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.7.DeveloperTools --focusedUi
```

Or just [download the targeting pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168) and install it manually.

Also I think you need to update your windows to get it built in. You are running version 1511, .NET 4.7 gets installed with the version 1703 update (aka "Creators Update") .